# Trapezoid's area

Tags: geometry

> A trapezoid was inscribed into a semicirle of radius R. The side of
>   the trapezoid is slanting alpha against the base which is the diameter
>   of the semicirlce. Compute the area of the trapezoid.

So the base is 2R. The bad thing is: that's all I know. How should I move on? Don't know what to do with that angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reasonable brute force approach, using the standard formula for the area of a trapezoid.  We need a picture. Instead I will *label* the vertices, and rely on you to draw the picture. Please note that your picture is an essential part of the calculation below.

Let the vertices of the trapezoid be $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.  These labels go *counterclockwise*, and $A$, $B$ are the endpoints of the diameter of the semicircle, with $A$ on the left.  We assume that by "the side of the trapezoid is slanting $\alpha$ against the base" you mean that $\angle DAB=\alpha$.  Note that for the geometry to work, we need $\alpha \ge 45^\circ$. If $\alpha=45^\circ$, our "trapezoid" degenerates to a triangle.

Note that $\triangle ADB$ is right-angled at $D$.  It follows that $AD=2R\cos\alpha$.

Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to the diameter $AB$, meeting $AB$ at say $P$. Then by looking at $\triangle APD$, we can see that $DP=AD \sin\alpha=2R\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$. Progress, we now know the height of the trapezoid.

Now we sort of need to know the shorter one of the two parallel sides. Note that $AP=AD\cos\alpha=2R\cos^2\alpha$.

It follows that the shorter parallel side has length $2R-2AP=2R(1-2\cos^2\alpha)$.

So the *average* of the two parallel sides is $2R(1-\cos^2\alpha)$, which  simplifies to $2R\sin^2\alpha$.

Multiply the average of the two parallel sides by the height. We get 
$4R^2\sin^3\alpha\cos\alpha$.

**Comment**: We really didn't need to calculate the shorter parallel side, since it is obvious that our trapezoid has the same area as the rectangle of base $PB$ and height $DP$, and once we know that $AP=2R\cos^2\alpha$, we know that $PB=2R-2R\cos^2\alpha$.  And we didn't need the formula for the area of a trapezoid.

My preference would be to find the answer when the radius is $1$, then scale by the linear factor $R$ at the end, which scales the area by the factor $R^2$.

Comment: Thank you! So I get it right that $4R^2\sin^3\alpha\cos\alpha$ is the total area of the trapezoid?

Comment: @Bringiton: Of course you should check, I may be more  accident-prone than most. Go through the argument, it really is not fancy. Then check with a few examples for which you know the answer. For example, take $\alpha=45^\circ$. We get a degenerate trapezoid, actually a triangle. The formula says the area should be $4R^2(1/\sqrt{2})^4=R^2$. And it checks. (Note that we need $\alpha \ge 45^\circ$ for the geometry to work out.) The solution I gave is deliberately of a relatively unthinking kind. There are more elegant ways.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  both base angles are $\alpha$ to make the top parallel to the base.  Draw a radius to the upper corners and you have three isosceles triangles.

Comment: Oh, didn't see it! Thank you. Then we have two isosceles triangles with equal area and one with some other. How to count their areas, though?

What first hit my mind was that we should use $\frac{1}{2}2R*a*sinα$ but there seems to be no way to check what a (the second side touching the angle) equals.. Pythagorean theorem doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Bring Calculate the third non-alpha angle and then apply the formula.

Comment: Erm... we get this: http://i.imgur.com/sqnhc.png - how does that really help?

Comment: @Bringiton:  as you said above you have three isosceles triangles.  The matching two have areas $R^2\cos \alpha \sin \alpha$ (drop the altitude from the center and you have two right triangles).  What is the base angle of the other one?

Comment: Hmm.. The trapezoid can be inscribed in the circle so the opposite angles sum up to 180. Then, the base angles of the middle triangles are $180^\circ-2\alpha$. How to check its area, though?

Comment: @Bringiton:  the same formula for the other triangles works with the correction to the base angles.  The equal sides are again $R$, so the area is $|R^2\cos (\pi-2\alpha)\sin(\pi-2\alpha)|=|R^2\cos2\alpha\sin2\alpha|$

Comment: So the complete area of the trapezoid is $|R^2cos2αsin2α|$+$2( R^2cosαsinα)$=$|4R^2cos4αsin4α|$?

Comment: @Bringiton:  I agree with the left, but I don't see how you get from the left to the right.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos+%282x%29sin%282x%29%2B2sin%28x%29cos%28x%29-4sin%284x%29cos%284x%29 indicates it is not an identity.

Comment: So I can't shorten the left side in any way? Also, why is that an absolute value?

Comment: We don't need the absolute value once you get to $\cos 2\alpha$ as that is always $>0$.  When we had $\cos \pi-2\alpha$ that was $<0$.  If you like, you can use $2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=\sin2\alpha$ to go to $R^2(1+\cos2\alpha)\sin2\alpha$ if you like that better

Comment: So $|R^2cos(π−2α)sin(π−2α)|=R^2cos2αsin2α$, ok, but I meant shortening this: $R^2cos2αsin2α+2(R^2cosαsinα)$ to get the whole area. Can this be done in any manner?

Comment: Could you please help? I don't know if there's another way to write the whole area.

Comment: So is the whole sum $4R^2sin^3αcosα$?